# How to access an element within an element in css?

Tags: css, element

In the following code, how would I address the 'img' element in CSS? I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

```
<div id="random1">
<div id="random2">
<div id="random3">
<img src="images/image.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `>` immediate descendant selector like this:

```
#random3 > img{
  /* Css Rules */
}
```

Comment: Can you explain?: Does that apply to any element that has an `img` element three levels inside, or does it apply to all `img` elements having three levels outside? That is: Does the rule apply to the *inner* element, or does it apply to the *outer* element?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. If this is the extent of your markup (HTML), you can use element selectors (`img` and `div` are examples of elements) in CSS:

```
img {
    width: 500px;
}
```

If your markup will expand at a later date, you can use Classes (for multiple instances) or IDs (for unique instances). I'll show you classes and then IDs.

HTML:

```
<img class="myImg" src="images/image.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
.myImg {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Or for IDs, HTML:

```
<img ID="myImg" src="images/image.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
#myImg {
    width: 500px;
}
```

---

If you want to select the img as a child of the div `#random3`, you can use a direct descendant selector:

```
#random3 > img {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on some theory here... The more specific a selector is, the more priority it takes.  There's more to it than that, but that's the general gist.

Spaces between selectors basically say "child @ any depth" whereas a greater than symbol (>) states "immediate child only".  Immediate child selectors are more specific than any-depth selectors.

Any of these could style the image in your example:

```
#random1 #random2 #random3 img { blah }
#random1 img { blah }
#random2 img { blah }
#random3 img { blah }
```

So could this (because img is an immediate child of #random3):

```
#random3 > img { blah }
```

But this would fail, because the img is not immediately inside random2, it's inside random3 inside random2:

```
#random2 > img { blah }
```

So you could start off lazy with #random1 img.  If that failed to stick, #random3 > img as suggested.  If that happened to fail as well, just get more and more specific. As an example, where each line gets more and more specific

```
#random3 > img {}
#random2 > #random3 img {}
#random1 > #random2 > #random3 > img {}
```

And if that last one didn't work, you *really* need to look at some weirdo CSS because 3 immediate child selectors is kinda crazy talk.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to nest the listings:

```
#random1 {
//stuff
}

#random3 img{
//other stuff for the image
}
```

And so on.
This will localize the img sepecifically for random3, and not affect other img tags.